# Three odd Three even

Tags: sequences-and-series

I want a formula that generates evens when $x\equiv 1\pmod 6$,$x\equiv 2\pmod 6$and$x\equiv 3\pmod 6$and also generates odds when $x\equiv 4\pmod 6$,$x\equiv 5\pmod 6$and$x\equiv 5\pmod 6$.

This is the way that you generate two even and two odds may help:

$\frac{x(x+1)}{2}$These numbers called triangle numbers I was thinking that the formula should be in the form of $ax^3+bx^2+cx+d$Am I right?Also a proof isn't needed but if it is a proof available It's better.

Comment: In my answer, I assumed that what you want is a formula that generates evens when $x≡1 \pmod{6}, x≡2 \pmod{6}$ and $x≡3 \pmod{6}$ and odds when $x≡4 \pmod{6}, x≡5 \pmod{6}$ and $\color{red}{x≡6 \pmod{6}}$, not as you wrote (check your first sentence). If this is not what you wanted, please let me know.

Comment: Typo in the third condition for odds!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function $\Psi:\mathbb{Z}^+\to\mathbb{Z}$, defined by, $$\Psi(n)=\left\lfloor\dfrac{\langle n\pmod 6\rangle}{3.5}\right\rfloor$$generates the sequence, $$0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,\ldots$$ where $\langle n\pmod 6\rangle$ denotes the least possible **positive integer** $r$ such that $n\equiv r\pmod 6$.

Comment: In general the function $\Psi:\mathbb{Z}^+\to\mathbb{Z}$, defined by, $$\Psi(n)=\left\lfloor\dfrac{\langle n\pmod {2m}\rangle}{\left(m+\dfrac{1}{2}\right)}\right\rfloor$$ generates a sequence of $m$ number of $0$'s followed by $m$ number of $1$'s where $Ψ(1)=0$.